# How to enlarge panel to contain long legends label

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have data that looks like [this](http://dpaste.com/1051194/plain/).

My current code here

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
pal <- c(brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"),brewer.pal(12,"Paired"));
dat<-read.table("http://dpaste.com/1051194/plain/",header=TRUE)
dat.sub <- data.frame(dat$Function,dat$Freq)
ggplot(dat.sub,aes(dat.Freq,color=dat.Function),shape=dat.Function)+ stat_density(geom="path",position="identity",size=0.5)
```

generate figures like below:
[image]

Note that the length of legend text caused the main plot to be squeezed.
What's the best way to deal with this so that the figures appear normal
and the legend also shown in its completeness?

Comment: Plot on a wider device

Comment: Either expand the window if using it interactively, or set the size of the device by using the `width` parameter of `ggsave`.

Comment: There's also the obvious option: use shorter labels in the legend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to place legend under the plot and then arrange labels in two columns.

```
ggplot(dat.sub,aes(dat.Freq,color=dat.Function),shape=dat.Function)+ 
  stat_density(geom="path",position="identity",size=0.5)+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",legend.direction="vertical")+
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2))
```

[image]